# How to load same page in php with different url

Tags: php

For example :

http://www.xyz.com/quality-management/six-sigma-green-belt-training-bangalore/ppa79dt31028

AND

http://www.xyz.com/quality-management/xyz/ppa79dt31028

getting the same result please help

Comment: study about .htaccess

Comment: use htaccess in code to rewrite url..

Answer (score 1):

create a htaccess file in your root folder and Try Rewrite Rules like :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/six-sigma-green-belt-training-bangalore/(.*)$ http://www.simplilearn.com/quality-management/six-sigma-green-belt-training/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file in your root and do something like

```
Redirect /foldername/filename.html http://www.mynewwebsite.com/foldername2/filename.html
```

More info about .htaccess:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files/

Answer (score 0):

You can use url rewriting. For this you need to enable rewrite_module in apache. See the following.
http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

http://www.iwebtool.com/htaccess_url_rewrite

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="index.php?url=url1">
<a href="index.php?url=url2">
```

and in your `index.php`

```
<?php if ($_GET['url1'] || $_GET['url2'] ){
// display content;
}?>
```

you can use this  or use .htaccess to write rules for your link  as suggested in above answers.